# Android lifecycle inversion

Tags: android, android-activity, lifecycle, inversion, onstart

I encountered somewhat confusing situation, so I wanted to ask a principle behind it.

scenario
: I have two activities A and B.
A is a launcher activity and A starts B activity.
I wanted to finish B activity and start B again.
the situation I called confusing starts here.
the normal scenario is I assume

1. B-onPause
2. A-onStart
3. A-onResume
4. B-onStop
5. B-onDestroy
   --> starts B
6. A-onPause
7. B-onCreate
8. B-onStart
9. B-onResume
10. A-onStop

but when I simulate this scenario as fast as possible(with my finger), this order does not remain.
like this

1. B-onPause
2. A-onStart
3. A-onResume
4. A-onPause
5. B-onCreate
6. B-onStart
7. B-onResume
8. A-onStop
9. B-onStop
10. B-onDestroy

I know that if activity A starts Activity B, the following order is fixed one (A-onPause -> B-onCreate -> B-onStart -> B-onResume).
Except resume and pause, another lifecycle callbacks are undeterministic?

I can simultate this on low-spec android device, but not on regular mid,high-spec device.

so one line question is
: when finishing and reopening activity, onStop and on Destroy can be done after onResume callback?

thanks in advance and sorry for bad english :)

Comment: `onStop()` will happen at some point after `onPause()`, but the `onDestroy()` is not really guaranteed to happen. this is also one of those things that should not be vendor-specific, but unfortunatelly - vendors' OEMs can tamper this (case in point - huawei miui, oppo and some other asian devices)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`onStop()` and `onDestroy()` are basically "cleanup" operations that can be performed **at any time** after the `Activity` is paused. You absolutely can not rely on these being called at any specific time.